# Is it possible for autohotkey to write inside its own script thats running?

Tags: autohotkey

I have a script with a list of words inside. I want to create a gui that opens up and allows users to enter words to the list and remove them aswell. Is it possible for the script to edit itself while running? If so, how would I go about doing this. Here is my current script.

```
Word1 = This
Word2 = Is
Word3 = A
Word4 = Test
Word5 = Script
Word6 = And
Word7 = I
Word8 = Like
Word9 = Apple
Word10 = Pie

Min := 1
Max := 10

Gui, New
Gui, Add, Text,, Please enter a word you wish to add:
Gui, Add, Edit, Word
Gui, Show

MButton:: 
   RandWords := "" 
loop,
{
    Random N, %Min%, %Max%  
    if( Last != N )
    { 
         Last := N
         break
    }
}
RandWords .= Word%N%
   Send %RandWords%{!} {enter} 
Return
```

Comment: You're asking two different things. Either you want an array of words or modify the code itself?

Comment: Those listed words are in the code. I want the code to be able to edit its own code.

Comment: No, those words are stored in variables (actually a pseudo array, look at the indexes), you want to edit variables, not the code itself.

Comment: Anyway, take a look at https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Input.htm and then just add the result to an unused index of 'array' `Word`.

Comment: Ok so I managed to create a file and have the code write to that txt file but I am having issues on removing a line from the file. Say I type in "Script" and have it remove that line containing "Script" aswell as keeping the format of the file correct.

Comment: It's very likely that everything is cleaner if you separate code and data. Create a separate file for the data and read&write to it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how to use arrays to store user input:

```
store :=
counter := 0
loop, 3
{
    InputBox , here , User input , Please enter some text!
    store%counter% := here
    counter++
}

store1 = This element was deleted!

counter := 0
loop, 3
{
    str := store%counter%
    MsgBox, %str%
    counter++
}
```

As you can see, `store` is used as a pseudo array, and is indexed using `counter`, or integer values.

There is a line that deletes (actually just changes, but you get the idea) the second element. It could have been written like this:

```
counter := 1
store%counter% = This element was deleted!
```